# React check authentication on startup

Tags: reactjs

I have a React website right now that requires a login. When you load the page, react needs to check whether you are logged in (by calling the webserver).

If the user is logged in (`isAuthenticated = true`) the user is shown the website and if (`isAuthenticated = false`) the login page is shown.

`isAuthenticated = false` by default so when the if the user is logged in the user briefly see the login page before user can be checked to be logged in.

How do other websites handle this issue? It looks like Facebook is able to know on startup whether you are logged in or not.

Comment: See `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. You can check status of user in that function.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the authentication set up already, you're just trying to prevent authenticated users from seeing the log-in page flash onscreen on initial load.

If that's the case, you could initially set `isAuthenticated` to a non-boolean value (`null` or `undefined`), show a loading component while authentication is occurring, and render the app only when ready.

For example, in your main App file, you could use something like:

```
render() {
   // use strict equality check
   return isAuthenticated === null ? <IsLoading /> : <App />
}
```

Where `<IsLoading />` is a loading spinner and `<App />` is the component you're currently rendering from the start.

Comment: Yes, I can do this, but then there would be a loading symbol. I was wondering how Facebook and other websites can get around this? (I don't see any loading when I go on there)

Comment: If avoiding any sign of loading is what you're looking for, there are a few ways to go about it, but it all depends on your current setup for authentication. Could you update your question to describe how you're handling that?